# how can I access an attribute by name, rather than by integer?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I must be missing something, but I can't seem to figure out how to get an Attribute by Name/String, only by an Integer, which is likely to change  (the Attribute Name is not).

Could you explain how I get Attributes by name/string? The string "active" attempt produces this error:

```
Error   82  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute>.this[int]' has some invalid argumens
```

Thank you!

Hairgami

```
using (sdb = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleDBClient(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID))
        {
                String selectExpression = string.Format("select * from apps where appid = '{0}'", appID);
                SelectRequest selectRequestAction = new SelectRequest().WithSelectExpression(selectExpression);
                SelectResponse selectResponse = sdb.Select(selectRequestAction);

                if (selectResponse.IsSetSelectResult())
                {
                    SelectResult selectResult = selectResponse.SelectResult;
                    foreach (Item item in selectResult.Item)
                    {
                        //Works fine
                        Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute id = item.Attribute[1];

                        //How can I do this:
                        Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute id = item.Attribute["active"];

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a [`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) like it's an associative array, which it's not. The [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) method could be used to achieve something similar:

```
Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute id = 
   item.Attribute.FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.Name == "active");
```

Comment: Thanks Donut! I didn't think of using a LINQ query or what every that is you're doing. That works perfectly. You rock all that is not tethered to the ground. Whoo-hoo!